# Load selected data using $(this).append(data) inside live

Tags: append, jquery

I use the following code to dynamically add input fields to form, based on this source:

```
http://www.infotuts.com/dynamically-add-input-fields-to-form-jquery/
```

Here's a part of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 2;
    $("#btnAddIngredients").click(function () {
        var newIngredientsData = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .attr("id", 'ingredientsData' + counter);
        newIngredientsData.html('<div id="ingredientsData'+ counter + '" class="row">' +
                    '<div class="col-ingredients">#'+ counter + ' : <select id="ingredient'+ counter + '" name="ingredient'+ counter + '" class="selectIngredients"><select/></div>' +
                    '<div class="col-extra"><input type="text" name="extra'+ counter + '" id="extra'+ counter + '" size="30" maxlength="100" /></div>' + 
                    '<div class="col-quantity"><input type="text" name="quantity'+ counter + '" id="quantity'+ counter + '" size="5" maxlength="30" /></div>' +
                    '<div class="col-unit"><select id="unit'+ counter + '" name="unit'+ counter + '" class="selectUnit"><select/></div>'+
                    '</div>');
        newIngredientsData.appendTo("#ingredientsList");
        counter++;
    });

    $(".selectIngredients").live("click",function () {
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).append('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
        $.post("getdata.php", {what: "ingredients"},
               function (data){
               alert(data);
               $(this).append(data);
               }
               ,"html");
    });
});
```

What i'm expecting is for the selected value to be populated every time I click on it But the only thing that appeared is `"<option value="">Loading...</option>"`, which I appended first. It seems `$(this).append(data)` didn't do it's job. nothing is being appended. The alert(data) above it correctly displays the contents that should be appended.

If I change `$(this).append(data);` to `$("#ingredients1").append(data);` for example, the select data is loaded correctly, but not when I use `$(this).append(data);`

What's wrong here? Why do the appends; in the function (data){} doesn't work, while the preceding `$(this).append('<option value="">Loading...</option>');` works correctly every time?

Comment: [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` isn't referring to the same element inside of the `post` closure, use a context variable:

```
var that = $(this);
$.post("getdata.php", {what: "ingredients"}, function (data) {
    alert(data);
    that.append(data);                           
});
```

Comment: I belive the proper term is "closure", isn't it?

Comment: @Travesty3 -- Yep it is, give me a moment.

Comment: @Travesty3 A function is *part of* a closure. The other part of a closure is the lexical referencing environment. This approach includes `that` in the referencing environment of the callback's closure.

Comment: I was thinking the entire code sample given in the answer is a closure. But I could be wrong. The term confuses me.

Comment: wow tymeJV.. thanks a lot for the answer. never knew jquery (or javascript for that matter) has 'that'. if not for your reputation, I'd have thought you're joking.. :D

Comment: @imin: `that` is just a JS variable. It could have just as easily been called `blah` (or anything else you want to name it).

Comment: Yes, `that` is a custom var, like Travesty3 said, we could call it `blah` and it would be fine :)

Comment: @Travesty3 You can think of a closure as a combination of 1) functional code and 2) all the external variables that the functional code can access (called its "referencing environment"). When you execute a `function() { }` statement in JS, you create a closure, because (behind the scenes) the JS interpreter keeps track of all the variables available to that function. Thus, you can say that each function in JS *is* a closure, because each function is accompanied by a referencing environment. You might also say that a function is *part of* a closure because functional code is half of a closure.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` in your ajax response is the window, not the `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "context" setting for ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ... and it transfer "this" to the success scope